# How to add more than one header(HDRs) and object in a makefile?

Tags: python, c++, makefile, physics, root-framework

HDRS = EventLoop.h Data.h
OBJS = EventLoop.o Data.o
dict_$(PROGRAM).o

This is from my makefile, I want to add another Data.h and Data.o in it , kindly help!
Tried adding it infront/ on the next line but is giving errorrs

when I add more than one header and obj in the same lines it gives this error, maybe it has something to do with the dict declared below?
`EventLoop.h: No such file or directory #include "EventLoop.h" ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. <builtin>: recipe for target 'EventLoop.o' failed make: *** [EventLoop.o] Error 1`

Comment: Did you give space and add?? something like EventLoop.o data.o

Comment: yeah I did add space and backslash at the end, I've added the errorin my post.

Answer (score 2):

Which errors are you getting? You can add multiple files to a variable by using space to separate them

```
HDRS = EventLoop.h Data.h
```

Comment: g++ -O3 -Wall -fPIC -g -std=c++11 -pthread -std=c++11 -m64 -I/home/maryam/Downloads/root/include -I.   -c -o EventLoop.o EventLoop.cpp
EventLoop.cpp:1:10: fatal error: EventLoop.h: No such file or directory
 #include "EventLoop.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'EventLoop.o' failed
make: *** [EventLoop.o] Error 1
 this is the error I'm getting

Comment: is it related to the dict after the OBJ?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the `EventLoop.h` header file inside the `/home/maryam/Downloads/root/include` or `./` directories that you specified for the g++ compiler with the `-I` flag. Can you check if is this the case?